# GCE Use Cloud Storage Bucket as Mounted Drive

Tags: webserver, storage, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to mount a storage bucket to an instance so it can be used by the webserver as storage? If not, how can I add more storage to the instance without adding another persistent disk with an OS?

Comment: In GCE there is no more ephemeral disks. All disk is persistent disk. Secondly, Google Cloud Storage..even if its mounted to disk would not give you any reliable performance in comparison to persistent disk. Cloud Storage is object storage and not block device. You are better of using persistent disk they only cost $0.04/GB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can certainly create a new (larger) Persistent Disk and attach it to your instance as a data disk. This is a very good option, since it keeps your website data separate from your operating system. See the [Persistent Disk docs](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks) for details on all the options.

In your case:

- [Create a new Persistent Disk](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#create_disk) for the data. Pick a size large enough for your data and large enough to get the I/O throughput you want. (See [this chart](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdperformance) for details)
- [Attach the disk to your instance.](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attachdiskrunninginstance)

Comment: This doesn't explain how to mount a storage bucket, just how to add a persistent disk to a server.

Comment: This is an answer to the second question: "How can I add more storage to the instance wihtout adding another persistent disk with an OS?"

Answer (score 2):

Aside from attaching a new persistent disk, you could also use a number of FUSE based utilities to mount either a Google Cloud Storage or AWS S3 bucket as a local disk.

s3fs:
    *Can work with Google Cloud or AWS
    *Bucket can be mounted on multiple systems at same time
    *Files are stored as objects on the bucket, so the files can be manipulated externally
    *A con is that it can be a little bit slow if you have a lot of files

S3QL:
    *Can work with Google Cloud or AWS
    *Bucket can be mounted on one system
    *Files are stored in a proprietary format, can't be manipulated outside of the mounted filesystem
    *Much faster than s3fs for many files
    *Doesn't handle network connectivity issues so well (manual fsck and remount if you lose network).

Hope this helps.